# column to keep count of attempts to INSERT a row that already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, primary-key

I'm trying to create a column and make it count the number of tries of insert that the user make.

An example would make things much clearer :

```
+-------+----------------------------------+--------------+
| text  |            md5                   | insert_times | 
+-------+----------------------------------+---------+----+
| 123   | 202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70 |     834      |  
| abc   | 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72 |     923      |      
+-------+----------------------------------+--------------+
```

where `text` is a primary key.
Whenever a user tries to inserts `123` (using `INSERT IGNORE` to not get error messages because `123` already exists), the `insert_times` would increase by `1`, keeping track of number of tries of inserting an already existing text in the table.

Any ideas on how to make it? 
I cannot make triggers because my db host (godaddy) doesn't allow triggers. 
If not possible to do in `mysql`, can I pull it off with the help of `php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this within a single, simple query, simply use the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) function within MySQL. With this you simply do your INSERT followed by what needs to be updated in the 'duplicate' row. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (text, md5, insert_times) VALUES ('abc', {MD5}, 0}
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE insert_times+1;
```

However, I personally prefer the PHP approach, as in most of my queries things usually aren't as cut and dry as a simple update:

```
$res = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT text FROM tbl WHERE text = '%s'", $text));
if (mysql_num_rows($res) != 0)
{
    mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE tbl SET insert_times+1 WHERE text = '%s'", $text);
}
else
}
    mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl SET text = '%d', md5 = '%s'", $text, $hash);
}
```

This method leaves for more room to do trigger other events/ functions as well, if needed.

Comment: this helps very much! i'd appreciate it if you could help me find an SQL solution only, if you cant then its alright! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

check whether that record already exist in the table for that purticular key, If yes, update the insert_times value to `insert_times+1`; , else create a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You could put some logic in your script that would check to see whether the row exists before attempting to insert it. If it doesn't exist, do the INSERT query. If it does, increment the insert_times field.

You could also keep a separate insert_attempts table that doesn't have the uniqueness constraint. For every attempt to insert a row, you would do two queries: the one that you're doing now, plus one to insert_attempts. The one to insert_attempts could either insert a new row, and you'd COUNT() the rows with the relevant ID, or it could just check the number associated with that ID and update it.